# SQL select cell contents as column for dynamic range

Tags: sql, select, dynamic, range

I have a BEFORE table as the initial format and an AFTER table as the ideal format:

[Select "Printer:" cells to column with corresponding data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XWjL.png)

Is it possible to select the corresponding 'Printer:%' above each small table into a left column by some sort of lookup/filter/dynamic rule where the numbered contents will vary in length as we receive this monthly report? I believe the relative ending line of each table will say "Not assigned" which may be able to be used as a stop. Thank you for considering.

Comment: Is there anything that shows which rows belong to which printer?  Or is it simply the rows 'beneath' the record?  Order of rows isn't the easiest thing to use and order can change.  Type of DB you are working in would help

Comment: MSSQL 2016 r2. Yes, no indicator in the numbers; just "beneath", which seems to be the tricky piece. The table comes from an excel sheet with a lot of graphics, having the numerical data below the printer IPs, e.g.
Date
printer IP 

Thanks.